# Send email with template but show css code to user

Tags: email, html-email

I have email template with simple css. I send email to user but it show css code to user and template is not working correctly.
I test by sent email to myself on Gmail It work correctly.
and problem is I don't have enough data what kind of email client that they use.
If it possible I want to avoid using email with text only.[image]

First image is what user get.
Second image is what I test and got on gmail
[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        @media screen {
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qIIYRU-oROkIk8vfvxw6QvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: 700;
                src: local('Lato Bold'), local('Lato-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/qdgUG4U09HnJwhYI-uK18wLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 400;
                src: local('Lato Italic'), local('Lato-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/RYyZNoeFgb0l7W3Vu1aSWOvvDin1pK8aKteLpeZ5c0A.woff) format('woff');
            }

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Lato';
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: 700;
                src: local('Lato Bold Italic'), local('Lato-BoldItalic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/HkF_qI1x_noxlxhrhMQYELO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
            }
        }

        /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
        body,
        table,
        td,
        a {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }

        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }

        /* RESET STYLES */
        img {
            border: 0;
            height: auto;
            line-height: 100%;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
        }

        body {
            height: 100% !important;
            margin: 0 !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
        a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* MOBILE STYLES */
        @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
            h1 {
                font-size: 32px !important;
                line-height: 32px !important;
            }
        }

        /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0;"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;">

<div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1px; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;"> We're thrilled to have you here! Get ready to dive into your new account. </div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#2194F4" align="center">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 10px 40px 10px;"> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#2194F4" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px; border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px; color: #111111; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 48px; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 4px; line-height: 48px;">
                        
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="center" style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 20px 30px 40px 30px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">We're excited to have you get started. First, you need to confirm your account. Just press the button below.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="padding-right:10px;border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#2194F4">
                                                <a href="xxxx" target="_blank" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #2194f4; display: inline-block;">Confirm Contract</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr> 

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="padding: 20px 30px 60px 30px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" style="padding-right:10px;border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor="#65F489">
                                                <a href="xxxx" target="_blank" style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 2px; border: 1px solid #65F489; display: inline-block;">View Contract</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="left" style="padding: 0px 30px 40px 30px; border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; color: #666666; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 25px;">
                        <p style="margin: 0;">Cheers,<br> Team</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `is not working correctly` is not enough to propose a solution

Comment: Please show your code or a screenshot of what "show css code" looks like

Comment: I added picture

Answer (score 0):

When you send an email like this you will want a fallback. The person receiving the email can set the email up so he will see text only. You want to create a multipart message. This might help you out, so both types get content. [Multipart MIME Email Guide](https://gist.github.com/tylermakin/d820f65eb3c9dd98d58721c7fb1939a8) or here: [How do I send a multipart email (both HTML and plain text)](https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2681)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're forwarding the email - emails will get reformatted according to the native styles of the specific email application. There's very little we can do to control that. If you want to test what it will look like, you need to send to them directly. You can use something like https://putsmail.com/ if you need.

However, not sure why the @font-face declaration are showing on forward. They shouldn't be. I suggest removing them from the `@media screen { ... }` - you don't need that. Just have `@font-face { ... }` declarations on their own.